# Diferencia String y StringStream

Tags: c++

Estoy ojeando la libreria sstream y me he topado con stringstream. Googleando llego a la conclusion de que es lo mismo que string, pero no llego a entenderlo.

Segun entiendo, es para crear un string y usarlo a modo "cin" para concatenar?

```
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream

int main () {

  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << 100 << ' ' << 200;

  int foo,bar;
  ss >> foo >> bar;

  std::cout << "foo: " << foo << '\n';
  std::cout << "bar: " << bar << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*Segun entiendo, es para crear un string y usarlo a modo "cin" para concatenar*", no vas muy desencaminado. Y precisamente por eso un `string` y un `stringstream` no son lo mismo, un `string` no permite inyectar (`<<`) datos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Los *streams* son bufferes de salida y/o entrada. A través de ellos se presenta una interfaz más o menos unificada que te permite acceder a diferentes orígenes de datos de forma homogénea.

Puedes usar un *stream* de salida para almacenar datos en un fichero, para escribir esa misma información en la pantalla o para sacarla por la impresora y lo mismo es aplicable para los *streams* de entrada.

`stringstream` es un *stream* que trabaja sobre un buffer interno. No escribe en ficheros ni lee de teclados. Lo que envías a ese *stream* acaba en la memoria. ¿Para qué sirve? Generalmente para usos internos.

La clase `string` en cambio representa físicamente una cadena de caracteres y su interfaz está diseñada para almacenar y gestionar cadenas de caracteres.

Algunas diferencias entre ambas clases:

- `string` no tiene sobrecargado el operador de inserción / extracción. Si no es un buffer no necesita comportarse como tal.
- `string` no es capaz de convertir tipos nativos.
- `stringstream` no dispone de iteradores. Un buffer es un almacen de información, para usarla antes hay que desempaquetarla. Esta característica impide que se pueda usar de forma directa con la inmensa mayoría de las funciones de la STL.
- `stringstream` no admite una redimensión explícita de su buffer interno.
- No puedes volcar de forma directa el contenido de `stringstream` en otro buffer. Para ello tienes que extraer su contenido (por ejemplo mediante el método `toString()`).
- Las utilidades de `iomanip` son aplicables con `stringstream` pero no con `string`.

Answer (score 9):

A grandes rasgos, un `stringstream` es, básicamente, un *buffer* en memória que simula comportarse como un archivo. Simple y sencillo.

Permite las mismas operaciones que permitiría un *stream*, **pero no está ligada a ningún dispositivo físico**; todas las operaciones se efectúan en memoria, usando un *string* como *almacén*.

Mientras que un *stream* **no permite** acceder al dispositivo físico subyacente, una *stringstream* **si permite** acceder al *stream* que usa como *buffer*, mediante las operaciones

```
td::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator> str() const;
```

para **obtener** una copia del *buffer*, y

```
void str(const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& new_str);
```

para establecerlo nosotros.

Answer (score 3):

Los `stringstream` se utilizan fundamentalmente para operaciones con formato sobre `string`s, al igual que los `fstream`s hacen lo propio con ficheros.

Puedes utilizar todos los functores que tienen los `iostream`s para manipular el flujo como el formato de entrada/salida de números (`std::hex`, `std::scientific`, etc...), de cadenas (`std::quoted`), rellenos (std::setw, `std::setfill`), configuraciones de localización (`.imbue()`, `std::put_money`), etc.

En otras palabras, que si `iostream` junto a sus sobrecargas de los  `operator<</>>`s es la alternativa C++ de `printf`, `fstream` lo es de `fprintf`, y `stringstream` es de `sprintf`, además de *type safe* y con sintáxis mucho más cómoda, además de iterable (`std::istream_iterator` y `std::ostream_iterator`, para poder utilizar flujos como si fueran contenedores).

Answer (score 0):

```
include<sstream>
include <iostream>
include<string>
using namespace std;


struct profesor{
   string nombreCompleto;
   string carrera;
   string dni;
   int edad;
};

/*

    cout << "Enter title: ";
    getline (cin,films[n].title);
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> films[n].year;
*/





int main(){
    
profesor pn[3];
    string strEdad;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<"Ingresar nombre completo"<<endl;
        getline(cin,pn[i].nombreCompleto);
        //cin.getline(pn[i].nombreCompleto,50);
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingresar carrera"<<endl;
        getline(cin,pn[i].carrera);
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingresar DNI"<<endl;
        getline(cin,pn[i].dni);
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingresar EDAD"<<endl;
        getline(cin,strEdad);
        stringstream(strEdad) >> pn[i].edad;
        cout<<endl;
    }

    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        cout<<pn[j].nombreCompleto<<"\t"<<pn[j].carrera<<"\t"<<pn[j].dni<<"\t<<pn[j].edad<<endl;
    }


}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow, es genial que quieras aportar, aunque tu respuesta quedaría mucho mejor si das una breve explicación del porque y como lo que mencionas soluciona el problema de OP. Saludos ;)