# como almacenar contenido de variable en un espacio de un arreglo de string. C++

Tags: c++, array

Tengo un arreglo de string, en el cual quiero almacenar oraciones. Dichas oraciones contienen variables, como le indico a C++ que dentro de las oraciones hay variables?. No quiero imprimirlas en pantalla, por lo cual opciones como cout o printf no me sirven. Solo quiero que se almacenen en el arreglo.

En el código de abajo uso los << como en cout, ya se que esto no funciona así, lo pongo porque quizas queda mas claro lo que quiero hacer.

Gracias!!

```
int main(){

int saldo = 1000;                   
int retirar = 75;       
int ingresar;   

string registro[20];

registro[0] = "Se retiraron " << retirar << " dolares del cajero automático. Quedan " << saldo << " dolares;

cout << registro[0];
```

}

Comment: Creo que deberías consultar [Diferencia String y StringStream](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/60358/19610).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). A grandes rasgos, esa clase permite usar todas las operaciones que se realizan con un *stream* (leer y escribir) usando una `std::string` como *almacén*.

Una vez realizadas las escrituras, puedes obtener **una copia** del *almacén* llamado a su función-miembro [`str( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main( ) {
  int saldo = 1000;
  int retirar = 75;

  string registro[20];

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "Se retiraron " << retirar << " dolares del cajero automático. Quedan " << saldo << " dolares.\n";

  registro[0] = std::move( ss.str( ) );

  std::cout << registro[0];

  return 0;
}
```